# High accuracy but bad predictions on Keras Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have a 9 class dataset with 7000 images, I use MobilenetV2 for training my set and ImageGenerator, resulting in 82% percent val accuracy. But when i predict my test images, it always predicts a false class. I have no idea what is wrong with it.Here is my code;

My ImageGenerator:

```
image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range = 20,
                               width_shift_range=0.12,
                               height_shift_range=0.12,
                               shear_range=0.1,
                               zoom_range = 0.06,
                               horizontal_flip=True,
                               fill_mode='nearest',
                               rescale=1./255)
```

My model:

```
Model = Sequential()

Model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=image_shape,activation='relu'))
Model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

Model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=image_shape,activation='relu'))
Model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

Model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=image_shape,activation='relu'))
Model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

Model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=image_shape,activation='relu'))
Model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

Model.add(Flatten())

Model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))

Model.add(Dense(9,activation='softmax'))
```

MobilenetV2:

```
height=224
width=224
img_shape=(height, width, 3)
dropout=.3
lr=.001
class_count=9 # number of classes
img_shape=(height, width, 3)
base_model=tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2( include_top=False, input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max', weights='imagenet') 
x=base_model.output
x=keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
x = Dense(512, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu', kernel_initializer= tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=123))(x)
x=Dropout(rate=dropout, seed=123)(x)        
output=Dense(class_count, activation='softmax',kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=123))(x)
Model = keras.models.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
Model.compile( loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],optimizer='Adamax')
```

My Rlronp:

```
rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=1, verbose=1, mode='auto', min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0)
```

My train_image_gen:

```
train_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                target_size=image_shape[:2],
                                                color_mode='rgb',
                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                class_mode='categorical')
```

My test_image_gen:

```
test_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                                target_size=image_shape[:2],
                                                color_mode='rgb',
                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                            class_mode='categorical',shuffle=False)
```

My earlystop:

```
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=4)
```

My Model fit:

```
results = Model.fit(train_image_gen,epochs=20,
                              validation_data=test_image_gen,callbacks=[rlronp,early_stop],class_weight=class_weight
                              )
```

Training and accuracy:

```
Epoch 20/20 200/200 [==============================] - 529s 3s/step -
 loss: 0.3995 - accuracy: 0.9925 - val_loss: 0.8637 - val_accuracy: 0.8258
```

**My problem is** when i predict an image from test set, it predicts the false class, 90% of time.

For example here, it has to be 3rd class, but max is on 2nd class.

```
array([[0.08064549, 0.04599327, 0.27055973, 0.05219262, 0.055945  ,
        0.25723988, 0.07608379, 0.10404343, 0.05729679]], dtype=float32)
```

**I tried** collecting my own dataset with 156 class and 2.5k images, but it was even worse.

My loss on 20 epochs:
[image: loss]

Comment: How frequent is each class?

Comment: I don't see train_image_gen or test_image_gen. Are you sure those are producing comparable data?

Comment: between 300 and 1500 @gtancev

Comment: Forgot it, sorry, edited. @BobbyOcean

Comment: It would appear that you still get ~82% accuracy on your generated test data (from the test_image_gen set), since that is the last statement of your epochs. If so, the problem might be too much variation in your generator, so that the original information is not being learned. At 20 epochs with 200 batches at 32 units a batch, you only trained on 128,000 images from a collection of 7,000 (which is like 18 new images to each true image, your degrees of freedom in your generator should reflect that). What happens if you bi-pass the generator and train on the 7,000 images directly?

Comment: Oh, i dont know how to do it exactly, what should i pass to Model.fit as the first parameter? @BobbyOcean

Comment: @PertevMeriçKutan (I have not worked with images extensively, so I am guessing) But if you set all your generator values to not have any degrees of freedom (like set them all to zero or one) so that there is no variation that should allow you to train without variation. Of course, we run the risk of overfitting by doing this. Experimentally we are just trying to see why your test_image_gen is giving 82% validation, but your actual data is not.

Comment: It still outputs 80% validation with no variation on the generator. @BobbyOcean

Comment: @PertevMeriçKutan And do you still only get 10% accuracy on the test images?

Answer (score 2):

accuracy: **0.9925**; val_accuracy: **0.8258**

Clearly the model is overfitted,

1. Try using regularization techniques such as L2,L1 or Dropout, they will work.
2. Try to Collect More data(Or use data augumentation)
3. Or search for other Neural Network Architectures
4. The best method is plot val_loss v/s loss

```py
r = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=15)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(r.history['loss'], label='loss')
plt.plot(r.history['val_loss'], label='val_loss')
plt.legend()
```

[image: Plot]

and check the point where `loss` and `val_loss` meet each other and then at the point of intersection see the number of epochs (say x) and train the model for x epochs only.

Hope you will find this useful.

Comment: I edited the post and added loss values in 20 epochs. So should where exactly should i stop? Also, i have an early stop monitoring val_loss, that doesnt meant to be stop epochs when it detects overfitting? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Model is overfitted...use dropout layer.. I think it will help

```
Model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

Comment: Doesn't the last epoch with an validation accuracy of 82% mean that it is not over fitting?

Comment: Check the loss values for overfitting. @BobbyOcean

Comment: Loss starts out with 5 and goes down to this numbers and even lower, i will try the Dropout and inform you.@Frightera

Comment: @Frightera I am not following. Yes, I agree that the model did too much training beyond 82% accuracy all the way to 99% (which consequently produces a small loss), and I agree that there is clear improvement possible (some over fitting), but the validation is still 82% on the test data. All things being equal if test_image_gen and the test images are random samples from the same population, there is no way that one would calculate 82% accuracy and the other 10%. My conclusion is that they are not representative samples of the same population.

Comment: Added it and updated the post with loss values for 20 epochs.Is it still overfitting or underfitting? Also still predictions are false.

Comment: did you normalize test data?

Comment: I think i did not @AdittaDas

Comment: only normalize test data....no need to augmentation...